# How to restrict growth (size) of layout in Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, layout, qt4, qt-designer

[image: This is my design]

When I maximize my window, I want to restrict a vertical layout (and the entire row below it also) so that it has a specific size (lets say a width of 200). How can I achieve this? Below is what I get now. The buttons are stretched too far. I want them to keep a width of 200.

[image: Window maximized]

Comment: @ekhumoro here is UI file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Xt-qsIjMucXfYuRcYvsmQr2_M3OD64j/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

To stop the buttons stretching, use the following steps in Qt Designer:

1. click on `scrollArea` in the Object Inspector
2. click on Break Layout on the toolbar
3. click on `scrollArea` in the Object Inspector
4. click on Lay Out in a Grid on the toolbar
5. click on `scrollAreaWidgetContents` in the Object Inspector
6. scroll down to the bottom of the Property Editor
7. change **layoutColumnStretch** to `0,1`

These steps should remove an empty column from the scroll-area grid-layout, and make the second column stretch to take up the available space when the window is resized.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to restrict the [maximum width](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#maximumWidth-prop) of all widgets (in this case the buttons) within the layouts of this grid column to the expected size, else they'll just keep expanding. You may also have to fiddle the horizontal [size policy](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum); I seem to remember that buttons were a bit tricky in this regard (or was that the height?), but can't test it right now.

The [layout size contraint](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#SizeConstraint-enum) you tried only applies to the layout's direct parent widget, if it has one, which isn't the case for the vertical layouts here.